# How can i Pass the Object Method and string as parameter for SignalR from Server to Client?

Tags: c#, jquery, service, client, signalr

I am new to signalR.I need to pass 2 values from signalr server to client.
The values are,

1.object method values

2.String value

here is my SignalR Hub Class:

```
[HubName("serviceHub")]
public class ServiceHub : Hub
{
public  void Send(string Displayname,object data)
    {
  var service = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServiceHub>();
  service.Clients.All.addMessage(Displayname,data);
}
}
}
```

and My Owin startup class:-

```
public class Startup
{
   public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
       app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

And My signalR passing values in Service:-

```
dict.Add(dashboardItem.ReportName ?? dashboardItem.Name, GetWidgetData(dashboardItem, null, null, null, null, false));

dict.Add(dashboardItem.ReportName, GetWidgetData(dashboardItem, null, null, null, null, viewerActions.Select(viewerAction => viewerAction.Control == dashboardItem.ReportName && viewerAction.ErrorOccurred).Any()));
```

above given , **dashboardItem.ReportName** is a string and GetWidgetData is an object method

[image: GetWidgetData]

and the javascriptClient is:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function(e) {
var service = $.connection.serviceHub;
            service.client.addMessage = function (Displayname, data) {
                $('div.container').append('<p><strong>' + Displayname + "="
                     + data + '</strong></p>');
            };
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log("Connected");
            }).fail(function () {
                console.log("Could not connected");
            });

        });
});
```

Am i wrote Correct?

If i did anything wrong in code,please give me a comment for that.

anybody provide me an solution to solve this?

How can i Pass the object method and string  as parameter for signalr from service to client?

am i wrote the javascript reciever is correct?

Comment: Apperantly, there is nothing wrong with you Hub class and javascript code, where and how are you calling `Send` method and what do you mean with _object method_ ?

Comment: I am mentioned object  method as  Dictionary<string,object> value.I need to pass the dictionary object value from server to client